# ANSI C strstr() not working with pointers

Tags: c, strstr, strncpy, string.h

I'm trying to use strstr() to find a substring in a string. Using char[] works only, char* is not working, gives segmentation fault.

So this one is working:

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "apple apple peach";
    char *p;

    p = strstr(str, "peach");
    if (p!= NULL) {
        strncpy(p, "apple", 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this one is not working:

```
int main() {
    char *str = "apple apple peach";
    char *p;

    p = strstr(str, "peach");
    if (p!= NULL) {
        strncpy(p, "apple", 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This one is neither:

```
int main() {
    char *str = "apple apple peach";
    char *peach = "peach";
    char *p;

    p = strstr(str, peach);
    if (p!= NULL) {
        strncpy(p, "apple", 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And neither this one:

```
int main() {
    char *str = "apple apple peach";
    char peach[] = "peach";
    char *p;

    p = strstr(str, peach);
    if (p!= NULL) {
        strncpy(p, "apple", 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is that a known bug or feature?

Comment: This is not a problem of `strstr`. You can not write into string constant. It is placed into read-only part of memory.

Comment: To OP: Compile with -Wwrite-strings to get a warning about this issue.

Comment: or better with -Wall and -Wextra, when you use gcc or use the equivalent flags for your compiler. and check every warning.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123. Note that write-strings is _not_ enabled by -Wall -Wextra. It used to be, but not anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***string-literal* is not safe to modify!** The one with `char[]` was successful only because `strncpy(p, "apple", 5);` modified the copied version of *string-literal*, **not the *string-literal* itself**. The relevant paragraphs in the standard read:

> ### 6.4.5, paragraph 6
>
> ... **The multibyte character sequence is then used** to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence...
>
> ### 6.4.5, paragraph 7
>
> ... If the program **attempts to modify such an array**, the behavior is undefined.

In short, string-literal is **(conceptually)** replaced with an array, and it's not safe to modify this. Note that *string-literal* is not necessarily const-qualified, although MSVC++ seems to mandate that *string-literal* is `const char *` or something that's const-qualified.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is *not* with `strstr`, it's with `strncpy`.  In the pointer case, you're using `strncpy` to try to write to *string literal*, which is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with `strstr`: it works as expected. The crash happens in `strcpy`, when you attempt to *modify* memory allocated to string literal. This is undefined behavior.

The key to solving this problem is placing the data into memory that allows writing. Your first program does so by declaring `str` an array:

```
char str[] = "apple apple peach";
```

That is not UB, so the program runs to completion. Another alternative would be to allocate `str` in dynamic memory, like this:

```
char *str = malloc(20);
strcpy(str, "apple apple peach");
char *p;
p = strstr(str, "peach");
if (p!= NULL) {
    strncpy(p, "apple", 5);
}
free(str);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. That was a point which was forgotten. :)